# How to get the parent dir name for a given dir in erlang?

Tags: erlang

In erlang, i have a dir `/proj/htdocs/root/jpT/elqstux/16-04-12/ct_run.ct_sim@esekilvxen263.2016-04-12_09.27.06/auto.suite.sbg_ft_esrvcc_midcall_SUITE.groups.esrvcc_midcall_media_stop_002.logs/run.2016-04-12_09.27.12/log_private/`,

I want get the parent dir name of this dir.
in this case, the expect result is `/proj/htdocs/root/jpT/elqstux/16-04-12/ct_run.ct_sim@esekilvxen263.2016-04-12_09.27.06/auto.suite.sbg_ft_esrvcc_midcall_SUITE.groups.esrvcc_midcall_media_stop_002.logs/run.2016-04-12_09.27.12/`.

But i try `dirname(Filename) -> file:filename_all()`, but i am not successed.

So, i want to know is there have this method for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your input path ends with `/`, you need to call `filename:dirname/1` twice (or you can remove it yourself and call `filename:dirname/1` once):

```
1> Path = "/proj/htdocs/root/jpT/elqstux/16-04-12/ct_run.ct_sim@esekilvxen263.2016-04-12_09.27.06/auto.suite.sbg_ft_esrvcc_midcall_SUITE.groups.esrvcc_midcall_media_stop_002.logs/run.2016-04-12_09.27.12/log_private/".
"/proj/htdocs/root/jpT/elqstux/16-04-12/ct_run.ct_sim@esekilvxen263.2016-04-12_09.27.06/auto.suite.sbg_ft_esrvcc_midcall_SUITE.groups.esrvcc_midcall_media_stop_002.logs/run.2016-04-12_09.27.12/log_private/"
2> Expected = "/proj/htdocs/root/jpT/elqstux/16-04-12/ct_run.ct_sim@esekilvxen263.2016-04-12_09.27.06/auto.suite.sbg_ft_esrvcc_midcall_SUITE.groups.esrvcc_midcall_media_stop_002.logs/run.2016-04-12_09.27.12/".
"/proj/htdocs/root/jpT/elqstux/16-04-12/ct_run.ct_sim@esekilvxen263.2016-04-12_09.27.06/auto.suite.sbg_ft_esrvcc_midcall_SUITE.groups.esrvcc_midcall_media_stop_002.logs/run.2016-04-12_09.27.12/"
3> filename:dirname(filename:dirname(Path)).
"/proj/htdocs/root/jpT/elqstux/16-04-12/ct_run.ct_sim@esekilvxen263.2016-04-12_09.27.06/auto.suite.sbg_ft_esrvcc_midcall_SUITE.groups.esrvcc_midcall_media_stop_002.logs/run.2016-04-12_09.27.12"
```

Your expected path also includes a trailing `/`, so you can manually append that as `filename:dirname` doesn't include it:

```
4> filename:dirname(filename:dirname(Path)) ++ "/" == Expected.
true
```